# iOS In-app purchase: confirm alert doesn't show

Tags: ios, storekit

I have had in-app purchases working in my (development) app for a few weeks now.  This morning (Feb 24, 2014) I tried to make a purchase.  The product info request when through no problem, but when I attempted to make a transaction, there was no response... while my app is in the foreground.  If I hit the "home" button to send my app to the background, the "enter password" or confirmation alert part of the transaction will appear.  The only way I am currently able to make purchases is to go to send my app to the background then quickly bring it back to the foreground, so the store kit alerts will show in my app and not on the dashboard.

I have not changed the store kit functionality in my app recently, so I'm thinking it might have something to do with how my app handles background/foreground execution, but I have no idea what it could be.  Anyone else having this problem and know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it has something to do with some image drawing that I was doing elsewhere in the app on a background thread.  Not sure yet how that interfered with this, or what I was doing incorrectly as far as multithreading is concerned.  I will update this answer if I learn more.  If anyone has any tips on this subject, they would be welcome.

UPDATE: Doing drawing while on a background thread without ending all of the image contexts that were created, that was the problem.  The CPU starts working at full speed trying to close them or something, and it makes the app slow, drains the battery, and for some reason caused this interference with the StoreKit purchase workflow.